# Trying to remove jQuery with vanilla javascript and cannot find equivalent of $('element1').html(element2)

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I am trying to remove all the jQuery from my code and I cannot find the vanilla javascript equivalent of this:

```
post_template=document.getElementById('post_template')
$("#modal-body").html(post_template);
```

I've tried the following, but it does not work:

```
post_template=document.getElementById('post_template')
document.getElementById('modal-body').html=post_template
```

If someone has a website that can show me all the methods of the getElementById object that would be super useful...Surprisingly all the documentation I've found doesn't explain all the options I can put after getElementById.

Comment: the JS equivelant of `.html('foobar')` is `.innerHTML = 'foobar'`

Comment: `getElementById` returns an `Element` object: you should be looking into the properties of `Element` instead :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element

Comment: @KyleRifqi That's fine for strings but not element objects

Comment: @charlietfl hmm thats true but you could just do `elm1.innerHTML = elm2.innerHTML`

Comment: @KyleRifqi Ok but now the original suggestion you made needs correcting. That's not how this should work

Comment: @KyleRifqi I did your second suggestion and it did what I wanted. Namely elm1.innerHTML = elm2.innerHTML